# Rspec + Devise + BaseController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

I'm creating a base controller for the admin section of a project. All controllers whitin the admin section will inherit from it.

```
#app/controllers/admins/base_controller.rb

class Admins::BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout "admin_cms"
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
end
```

-

```
#spec/controllers/admins/base_controller_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe Admins::BaseController do
  controller do
    def index
    end
  end

  describe "before_filter#authenticate_admin!" do
    before(:each) do
      @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
    end

    context "when admin is not logged in" do
      it "redirect admin to sign_in path" do
        get :index
        response.should redirect_to new_admin_session_path
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I've already inclueded Devise::TestHelpers on my spec_helper.rb and I'm getting this error when running this spec:

```
Admins::BaseController
  before_filter#authenticate_admin!
    when admin is not logged in
      redirect admin to sign_in path (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

   1) Admins::BaseController before_filter#authenticate_admin! when admin is not logged     in redirect admin to sign_in path
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template anonymous/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en],     :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0xbaf75d4>"
     # ./spec/controllers/admins/base_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.17124 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/admins/base_controller_spec.rb:16 # Admins::BaseController   before_filter#authenticate_admin! when admin is not logged in redirect admin to sign_in path
```

I changed my spec to this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admins::BaseController do
  controller do
    def index
      render nothing: true
    end
  end

  describe "before_filter#authenticate_admin!" do
    context "when admin is not logged in" do
      it "redirect admin to sign_in path" do
        get :index
        response.should redirect_to new_admin_session_path
      end
    end

  end
end
```

and now I'm getting this error:

```
Failures:

  1) Admins::BaseController before_filter#authenticate_admin! when admin is not logged in redirect admin to sign_in path
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to new_admin_session_path
       Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
```

So, for some reason it's not entering in the authenticate_admin! before filter. I'm kind of lost. Thanks again.

I'm using Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 2.0.0, Rspec-rails 2.13.0 and Devise 2.2.3. I really appreacite if someone could help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after 3 hours I discovered that the problem was on defining the anonymous controller.

instead of:

```
controller do
  def index
  end
end
```

I used:

```
controller(Admins::Base) do
  def index
  end
end
```

You need to specify always the anonymous controller you're testing unless is ApplicationController the one you're trying to test.